# iis7.5, web.config how to redirect not exist file(page) to another page?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, redirect, web.config-transform

I'm using `iis-7.5` and web.config file.

I want to redirect `"somepage.asp?id=63"` to `"somepage/10.html"`.

My web.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="301 Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="somepage.asp?id=63" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="somepage/10.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

it didn't work, when I change `<match url="somepage.asp?id=63" />` to `<match url="somepage.asp" />`, (delete ?id=63) , it worked, why? how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the url rewrite match url pattern doesn't match query string.

If you want to redirect the url according to the query string, I suggest you could try to use condition.

More details, you could refer to below url rewrite rule:

```
            <rule name="Redirect according to query string" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="somepage.asp" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=63" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="somepage/10.html" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```